# Redis Timeout Expired message on GetClient call

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis, redisclient

I hate the questions that have "Not Enough Info". So I will try to give detailed information. And in this case it is code.

Server: 
64 bit of https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/2.6/bin/release

There are three classes:

**DbOperationContext.cs**: https://gist.github.com/glikoz/7119628

**PerRequestLifeTimeManager.cs**: https://gist.github.com/glikoz/7119699

**RedisRepository.cs** https://gist.github.com/glikoz/7119769

We are using Redis with Unity ..

In this case we are getting this strange message:

"Redis Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use.";

We checked these:

- Is the problem configuration issue
- Are we using wrong RedisServer.exe
- Is there any architectural problem

Any idea? Any similar story?

Thanks.

**Extra Info 1**

There is no rejected connection issue on server stats (I've checked it via redis-cli.exe info command)

Comment: I've seen errors like this before. To fix it, I set the redis.conf timeout value to 30 and configured the `PooledRedisClientManager.IdleTimeOutSecs` to 30. This isn't exactly the same as your situation but maybe it's a new starting point.

Comment: I am getting same error. Did you find any solution? System.TimeoutException: Redis Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use. at ServiceStack.Redis.PooledRedisClientManager.GetClient()

Comment: Still there is no solution, but there is a clue.. Using both ReadonlyClient and Client seems problematic.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. I have multiple, different ASP.net applications, connected to the same redis server - some of the apps work, some work for like 5 minutes, then start throwing the timeout exception. INFO on the redis instance reports 40 active clients and no rejected connections. Going to try the timeout thingy - unless you managed to solve it in the mean time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have continued to debug this problem, and have fixed numerous things on my platform to avoid this exception. Here is what I have done to solve the issue:

**Executive summary:**

People encountering this exception should check:

1. That the PooledRedisClientsManager (IRedisClientsManager) is registed in a singleton scope
2. That the RedisMqServer (IMessageService) is registered in a singleton scope
3. That any utilized RedisClient returned from either of the above is properly disposed of, to ensure that the pooled clients are not left stale.

**The solution to my problem:**

First of all, this exception is thrown by the PooledRedisClient [because it has no more pooled connections available](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/pull/35).

I'm registering all the required Redis stuff in the StructureMap IoC container (not unity as in the author's case). Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497021/servicestack-redis-unable-to-connect-sport-50071) I was reminded that the PooledRedisClientManager should be a singleton - I also decided to register the RedisMqServer as a singleton:

```cs
 ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
 {
     // register the message queue stuff as Singletons in this AppDomain
     x.For<IRedisClientsManager>()
         .Singleton()
         .Use(BuildRedisClientsManager);
     x.For<IMessageService>()
         .Singleton()
         .Use<RedisMqServer>()
         .Ctor<IRedisClientsManager>().Is(i => i.GetInstance<IRedisClientsManager>())
         .Ctor<int>("retryCount").Is(2)
         .Ctor<TimeSpan?>().Is(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

     // Retrieve a new message factory from the singleton IMessageService 
     x.For<IMessageFactory>()
         .Use(i => i.GetInstance<IMessageService>().MessageFactory);
 });
```

My "BuildRedisClientManager" function looks like this:

```cs
private static IRedisClientsManager BuildRedisClientsManager()
{
    var appSettings = new AppSettings();
    var redisClients = appSettings.Get("redis-servers", "redis.local:6379").Split(',');
    var redisFactory = new PooledRedisClientManager(redisClients);
    redisFactory.ConnectTimeout = 5;
    redisFactory.IdleTimeOutSecs = 30;
    redisFactory.PoolTimeout = 3;
    return redisFactory;
 }
```

Then, when it comes to producing messages it's very important that the utilized RedisClient is properly disposed of, otherwise we run into the dreaded "Timeout Expired" (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597223/redis-servicestack-pooled-connection-client/10599194#10599194)). I have the following helper code to send a message to the queue:

```cs
public static void PublishMessage<T>(T msg)
{
    try
    {
       using (var producer = GetMessageProducer())
       {
           producer.Publish<T>(msg);
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: Log or whatever... I'm not throwing to avoid showing users that we have a broken MQ
    }
}

private static IMessageQueueClient GetMessageProducer()
{
    var producer = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMessageService>() as RedisMqServer;
    var client = producer.CreateMessageQueueClient();

    return client;
}
```

I hope this helps solve your issue too.

Comment: Hi @nover what do you use the IMessageFactory you have registered with IoC for? Cheers.

Comment: Actually, i think I figured it out - its called by the ServiceStack base Service class.

Comment: Hi @richardwhatever - the IMessageFactory is used internally in SS and is (from what I can read) required to be registered if you wish to use the MQ pattern :)